# Firefox DOM/CSS browser objects view - I can't seem to find how

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to figure out a complicated interaction between the browser and a couple of extensions, to see what's going on, and how the browser chrome (and its CSS) is being generated. I know it's there and possible, but I've tried all I can find, no luck.

I'm getting nowhere, and after 6 or 8 hours (whole day gone) I've tried everything I can find online. I know it's possible to view Firefox's browser object hierarchy - it's often needed for development. I've tried the inbuilt Inspector and a few other tools.

I hope it's on-topic here, I need help to figure how!

Comment: CSS is not generated. CSS interpreted by the browser. Often in violation of the standards. Also, many browsers have an initial CSS, which led to http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Not relevant to resolving problem, question isn't asking about CSS consistency and browser standards, or even about web page content at all.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try the Mozilla XUL Explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_Explorer.

Or the Extension Developers Extension might be a good start http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/extensiondev/

HTH

Comment: Those both explain how to mock up and test XUL on a small-ish scale, eg when developing. My issue is tracing how some chrome/UI is being calculated/generated in a full install of Firefox, with interacting extensions, in order to fix where extensions aren't giving rise to the desired overlays or CSS. Useful as they may be for prototyping/RAD, neither of these does what I asked: letting me inspect the chrome/UI of Firefox during runtime, much as Inspector probes a full web page's DOM model and structures. It should be easy (web pages say!) but I can't seem to get it working properly :)